# IntelliJ Problem with+get current working directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here is my maven project structure

```
ProjectParent
 -Class1
 -Class2
 -Module1 (another sub directory)
 --Module1Class1
 --Module1Class2
```

Now when I run Module1Class1 from IntelliJ my current working directory is where ProjectParent directory, but when I run Module1Class1 from eclipse, my current working directoru is ProjectParent/Module1 directory.

Why this is different in intellij & how can I change this, so my current directory is always from where my class started execution like in this example 'Module1Class1' directory.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should edit the template Run/Debug configuration and specify `$MODULE_DIR$` variable in the **Working directory** field.

All the new configurations will inherit this default setting and the variable will be substituted with the directory of the module that you want to run.

There is a feature request to make it the default setting, [please vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-52112).

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the working directory from within the run configurations dialog.

Comment: Worked for me.Thanks