# How to know (path) variable meaning in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, working-directory

I have read [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7462114/258483), that to set current directory of running program to module'r path, I need to write `$MODULE_DIR$` into setting:

[image]

But how would I know the meaning of this variable without Internet? Is there some list of such variables in `IntelliJ` or something?

`Path Variables` section in `Settings` does not contain this (and MAVEN_REPOSITORY is wrong).

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quite convenient IDE Idea offline help documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907801/quite-convenient-ide-idea-offline-help-documentation)

Comment: The button at the bottom right corner should help you.