# $MODULE_DIR$ points to .\.idea\modules

Tags: intellij-idea

According to this advice https://stackoverflow.com/a/7462114/258483 I set default configuration of Working Directory of run configurations to `$MODULE_DIR$`:

[image]

It was working for some time, but currently I noticed this points to

`MYPROJECT\.idea\modules`

which is incorrect. How to fix?

Where to find the list of definitions of such names as `$MODULE_DIR$`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$MODULE_DIR$
```

use

```
%MODULE_WORKING_DIR%
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

$MODULE_DIR$ seems to have been deprecated [gradle-baseline issue 280](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-baseline/issues/280). With the %MODULE_WORKING_DIR% at least for Gradle projects I can confirm that it is working as expected again.